# Hide UIButton in all ViewControllers with only one method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a one entry level question i.e in my project there is a same button in all ViewControllers in some cases I need to hide the button. Its easy to hide in individual ViewControllers with `buttonTitle.hidden=YES;` and I am thinking to hide this button in Single action from appdelegate or somewhere else which is better to do it. I am on the way to find the better solution for this, If anyone have idea about it please suggest me.

Comment: Is buttonTitle in your super class?

Comment: The all `ViewControlles` means those were appeared, do they include those `non-appeared` view controllers, which will appear in future ?

Comment: Use the observer pattern. Register each view controller that contains the button as observable. Send a notification when you want to hide your button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried but you can use singleton class for that. I mean, create an sub class of button and use share instance of that button in all controllers.

Or

Another solution will be, Which i have tried, Add button on `navigationController.view` which will show in all controllers. And when you hide, it will hide from all controllers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put following code in your AppDelegate (Use/Write code according to your requirment)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myButton"]) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"myButton"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
```

When you want to disappear button title

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"myButton"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Now, Replace all `buttonTitle.hidden=YES;` with following code

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"myObject"]) {
   buttonTitle.hidden=YES;
}
else
{
  buttonTitle.hidden=NO;
}
```

Comment: did you mean buttonTitle.hidden=YES; in every viewControllers which have button?

Comment: if you are using good design pattern, you may have to write only once.